# ¿Cómo agregar un componente a un sidemenu?

Tags: angular, ionic, router

Lo que he buscado es como agregar un componente a un *sidemenu* en *ionic* con *Angular*, he buscado pero no se muestra correctamente.

He importando el componente en mi **`app.module.ts`**.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi **`app.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DashboardComponent} from '../app/components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    { title: 'Dashboard', url: '/folder/Dashboard' , component: DashboardComponent , icon: 'mail' },
    // { title: 'Outbox', url: '/folder/Outbox', icon: 'paper-plane' },
    // { title: 'Favorites', url: '/folder/Favorites', icon: 'heart' },
    // { title: 'Archived', url: '/folder/Archived', icon: 'archive' },
    // { title: 'Trash', url: '/folder/Trash', icon: 'trash' },
    // { title: 'Spam', url: '/folder/Spam', icon: 'warning' },
  ];
  constructor() {}
}
```

Esto en **`folder-routing.module.ts`**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FolderPage } from './folder.page';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../components/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FolderPage
  },
  {
    path: '/folder/Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class FolderPageRoutingModule {}
```

Pero lo único que logro mostrar es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en mi componente solo tengo el contenido generado por default.

Intente seguir el siguiente post, pero igual no me mostraba:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136637/add-pages-to-sidemenu-of-side-menu-project-template

Quité el componente y agregué páginas.